# Create confusion matrix in R, using table() problem with missing values

Tags: r, machine-learning, data-science, confusion-matrix

Hi i have two vectors: predicts and targets and i have 3 classes "A", "B" and "C".

```
  targets = c("B", "A", "C", "C", "B")
  predicts = c("B", "B", "C", "C", "B")
```

and i want to create confusion matrix using this data. I want my output to look like this:

```
    A B C
  A 0 1 0
  B 0 2 0
  C 0 0 2
```

but for `table(targets, predicts)` i get this:

```
    B C
  A 1 0
  B 2 0
  C 0 2
```

Is it possible to fill the table with default values when missing class, like 0 for example?

Answer (score 0):

We can convert to `factor` with `levels` specified as all the `unique` values in both datasets and then use the `table`

```
lvls <- sort(union(targets, predicts))
table(factor(targets,levels = lvls), factor(predicts, levels = lvls))
```

-output

```
    A B C
  A 0 1 0
  B 0 2 0
  C 0 0 2
```